# Giving the value to the input inside one iframe that is inside the other iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe that has another iframe inside and I want to give a number to the input inside the second iframe.

How should I do this?

iframe code is something like this.

```js
$("#fram").contents().find("fram2").onload = 


$("#fram2").contents().find("#in01").value = "start"
```

```html
    <div> fram</div>
    <iframe id="fram" src="test.com"> 
    #document
        <iframe id="fram2" src="test1.com">
    #document     
            <div>
                <input id="in01">Some content</span>
            </div>
           
         </iframe>
           
    </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this.

If we use this code, the problem will be solved:
`$('iframe').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#in01').val('start')`